# how to sort hashmap by values?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

I need to sort my hashmap according to the values stored in it. The hashmap contains the contacts name stored in phone.also I need that the keys get automatically sorted as soon as I sort the values.or you can say the keys and values are bounded  together thus any changes in values should get reflected in keys.

```
 HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    map.put(1,froyo);
    map.put(2,abby);
    map.put(3,denver);
    map.put(4,frost);
    map.put(5,daisy);
```

required  output:

```
2,abby;
5,daisy;
3,denver;
4,frost;
1,froyo;
```

Comment: And also a near-exact duplicate of a question posted earlier today. -1 for reposting without even fixing the errors in the example.

Comment: it would be nice if you could have provided the answer..and by the way what errors in the example are you talking about.

Comment: You have `("1", froyo)` etc., when it's `<Integer, String>`.

Comment: oops I did not notice.my bad and thanks for reminding me..

Answer (score 0):

```
private static class MyMapComparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, String> a, Map.Entry<Integer, String> b) {
        return a.getValue().compareTo(b.getValue());
    }
}
...

List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>(map.entries());
Collections.sort(entries, new MyMapComparator());
```